# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to create a tinder swiping bot

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_driver_path = "C:/development/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://tinder.com/")

time.sleep(5)

sign_in_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="u-1035653303"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/button[2]/div[1]')
sign_in_btn.click()

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

I am using selenium webdriver to do this.
Above is the code in which, I'm trying to click login button on tinder website (https://tinder.com) to signin automatically using Facebook credentials in the next step.

but I am getting this error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element.
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated